# getElementsByTagName("name").lenght не находит длину

Tags: javascript

Долго мучился и написал банальщину ,а она не работает.

Это в отдельном файле который я подключил в `head` 
На выходе получаю `undefine`, хотя должен вывести `3`:

```
var aaa=document.getElementByTagName("span");
document.write(aaa.lenght);
```

Comment: Потому что length, а не lenght

Comment: Поскольку вы подключаете скрипт в хэд, у вас еще не сформирован в дереве элемент span, и его не находит. Попробуйте обрамить ваш скрипт в `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ });`

Comment: И потому что getElementsByTagName, а не getElementByTagName

Comment: @Oleksandr прежде, чем рекомендовать такие вещи, обратите внимание на ошибки в синтаксисе у ТСа

Comment: Oleksandr я попробовал... теперь просто не выходит на главную страницу и выводит undefine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте написание:

```js
var aaa = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
document.write(aaa.length);
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
<span>Lorem.</span>
<span>Lorem ipsum set.</span> 
  <br>
```

`elementS` - [getElementsByTagName('tagname')](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom#getelementsbytagname) (запоминается - ищем много тегов, а не один),
ну и `length` (th), а не `lenght`.

Comment: ... Ну я и М.Д..К буквы местами перепутал часа 2 искал и не нашел... Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, выполняется ли скрипт после того, как страница была сгенерирована. Для простоты добавьте скрипт в конце `<body>` или используйте `window.onload = function() {...call your functions...}`

Comment: Вставил в конец body не помогло, а с window.onload. тоже выводит только undefine и на главную страницу не выходит при запуске.   document.getElementById(id) находит по id даже не знаю играет это какуе-нибудь роль

Comment: вот пример, все работает https://codepen.io/yavor_makc/pen/EwPBZo посмотрите. может увидете разницу со своим кодом

Comment: Старайтесь не давать ответ "а может попробуйте". Лучше оставить коментарий.

Comment: @nick_n_a репутации не хватет для комментариев